# How to pull Deposits from QuickBooksOnline using IntuitAnywhere

Tags: asp.net, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am attempting to pull all the General Ledger entries from QuickBooksOnline into my C# Asp.net application for a given date range. I have been able to successfully pull Bills, Checks, and JournalEntries that match the Profit and Loss Detail report I'm using for reference. However, I seem to be missing all "Deposit" types from that report. I am pulling data for Invoices and Payments but they are coming back empty for the TxnDates I'm looking for.

In case it helps I'm including the Request and Response xml logs for Invoices and Payments.

Invoice Request

```
Filter=TxnDate :AFTER: 2013-02-28T00:00:00-05:00 :AND: TxnDate :BEFORE: 2013-04-01T00:00:00-04:00&PageNum=1&ResultsPerPage=100
```

Invoice Response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><qbo:SearchResults xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2" xmlns:qbp="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbopayroll/v1" xmlns:qbo="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbo"><qbo:CdmCollections xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Invoices"/><qbo:Count>0</qbo:Count><qbo:CurrentPage>1</qbo:CurrentPage></qbo:SearchResults>
```

Payment Request

```
    Filter=TxnDate :AFTER: 2013-02-28T00:00:00-05:00 :AND: TxnDate :BEFORE: 2013-04-01T00:00:00-04:00&PageNum=1&ResultsPerPage=100
```

Payment Response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><qbo:SearchResults xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2" xmlns:qbp="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbopayroll/v1" xmlns:qbo="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbo"><qbo:CdmCollections xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Payments"/><qbo:Count>0</qbo:Count><qbo:CurrentPage>1</qbo:CurrentPage></qbo:SearchResults>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deposits are not the same thing as an invoice or a payment. Deposits are a separate transaction indicating a deposit of a payment, to the bank.

According to Intuit's [documentation](http://ippdocs.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0400_QuickBooks_Online), querying for deposits is not supported by the v2 APIs.