# Quickbooks Online API financial data

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

Trying to build an application using data from the QuickBooks Online API. The reports aren't available through the API, but the data is. Well... most of it anyway. I haven't been able to find the transactions for Deposits like CreditCardCredits or bank transfers. This data is available on QuickBookOnline, but not through the API. They show up as Deposit transactions in the registers and ledgers.

I want to able to create rolling reports (financial statements) using the data from the API. Am I missing something, is this even possible? Currently using c# and the IPP API provided by Intuit via Nuget, I can switch to the REST calls if the data is available there or in any other format.

Thanks

Comment: Report APIs will be available in QB V3 API. It may take another 2/3 months. 

The following page will be updated when it is available. 
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v3/030_entity_services_reference/0500_v3_supported_entities_and_operations

Thanks

Comment: Thanks... gave up on developing this till V3 Reports API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The v3 APIs do not support reporting *yet*. It will eventually, it just doesn't yet.

You *might* be able to pull all of the individual transactions and sum things up... but unless you have an immediate need to do that, you're probably better off waiting until v3 supports reporting and building this functionality then.

The docs for what is/isn't supported are here:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v3/030_entity_services_reference/0500_v3_supported_entities_and_operations

Comment: Right we based on Manas and Keith's answers we gave up on building the Reports from individual transactions, will wait for V3 reports API for further development on that front. Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 1):

QBO Reports APIs are released recently in production. Updated devkit will also be published soon.

Please have a look at the following links

https://developer.intuit.com/blog/2014/03/25/the-quickbooks-online-reports-api-has-arrived

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/reports

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In fact, poorraj, I don't believe the data is available in any other format (at least in v3). With reference to Deposits specifically, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197414/how-do-you-access-bank-deposits-in-the-quickbooks-online-api) addresses their availability through v3.

If anyone happens to know if (and if so, how) poorraj can use v2 to get deposits (while he waits for Intuit to implement them in v3), that would be helpful knowledge here. The [latest post I can find on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347828/how-to-pull-deposits-from-quickbooksonline-using-intuitanywhere) indicates that deposits are NOT available even through v2.