# How Do You Access Bank Deposits in the QuickBooks Online API?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I'm getting started with the QuickBooks Online API, and between the documentation and Intuit's API Explorer, I can't seem to figure out how to query for bank deposits.  I thought it would be in journal entries, but it's not there.  I'm looking for simple deposits that are categorized to an income account.

Answer (score 0):

Deposits are not supported in QBO V3. I see you have [already raised](https://intuitpartnerplatform.lc.intuit.com/questions/817013-accessing-bank-deposits-via-the-api) the query on our community.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't pull down the link in Keith Palmer — Consolibyt's response [to this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347828/how-to-pull-deposits-from-quickbooksonline-using-intuitanywhere) (as I'm asked to login to something), it appears that v2 of the API didn't support them either, so it's not obvious that this feature is actually on the roadmap.

It's hard to believe there's *really* no way to access every type of transaction that can touch the GL, but I haven't seen any information to the contrary.